# Как перенести сайт на localhost

Tags: html, css, apache

Есть сайт (делал в рамках лабораторных работ) он расположен в папке, где находится html, css, js файлы. Установил Apache, php и у меня возникла трудность в размещении сайта на локальном сервере. Подскажите как можно это сделать?

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Openserver, denwer мануалов в сети уйма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно всё усложнять, устанавливая всё по отдельности, используй готовые сборки (см. https://ospanel.io/), там всё просто:

1) Устанавливаешь программу.

2) Создаёшь папку, где будет храниться сайт (там уже будет пример).

3) Перезагружаешь сервер

Всё готово, сайт открывается по тому адресу, который ты указал при создании папки. Если не хочешь юзать именно openserver, есть более лёгкий денвер.

Answer (score 0):

Материал из Википедии — свободной энциклопедии

> localhost (так называемый, «локальный хост», по смыслу — этот
>   компьютер) — в компьютерных сетях, стандартное, официально
>   зарезервированное доменное имя для частных IP-адресов (в диапазоне
>   127.0.0.1 — 127.255.255.255, RFC 2606). Для сети, состоящей только из одного компьютера, как правило, используется всего один адрес —
>   127.0.0.1, который устанавливается на специальный сетевой интерфейс «внутренней петли» (англ. loopback) в сетевом протоколе TCP/IP.